# coldfusion tinymce image upload

Tags: coldfusion, tinymce

I have a basic tinymce editor on the site, I want to be able to add any image from my local drive and upload to the server. I am using coldfusion, below is my current code. This only has option to insert the image url and not adding image from the local drive. I have not worked with plugins before so can anyone please give me what options can be used here. thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({ 
            // General options
            selector : "textarea#testone",
            width : 500,
            height: 200,
            theme : "advanced",
            skin : "o2k7",
            // Theme options            
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_path : false,
            theme_advanced_resizing : true
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Most editor plugins come with code for file upload handling done in various languages. look for a fileManager button to include and a filemanager class - it should have a way to configure a "handler" for the uploaded file. You will have to write the handler or modify a sample handler if provided.

Comment: Might try looking at the stuff over at riaforge.org. I have not used it, but the [ColdFusion File Manager for TinyMCE 4](http://filemanager4.riaforge.org/) looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Have read the documentation of the TinyMCE and they told like we cannot upload any images in a FAQ. Please look at the question [Here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:TinyMCE_FAQ#How_can_I_upload_image_files_from_my_local_computer.3F). We have an option called Insert/Edit images to insert images in the text content.